# if/else is not working in foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, if-statement

I'm new in PHP and I don't loop through all records using if/else statement in foreach loop.

$string = "a , b , 1, 2, 3, c, d, e";

```
$string = explode(' , ', $string);

foreach ($string as $value) {


    if(is_int($value)){

        echo 'Int ' . $value . '<br>';

    }else{


        echo 'Char ' . $value . '<br>';
    }


}
```

I get this result from above code,

### Output

Char a 
Char b 
Char 1, 2, 3, c, d, e

I expected following result, so kindly help me to figure out. Thanks

char a 
char b 
int  1 
 
int  2 
int  3 
char c 
char d 
char e

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the error or the solution...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Virtual Bird. Please take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php for more information involving is INT. As far as your code, the string does not appear to be an array, which would make Explode believe it is just a text string, instead of individual items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explode it by `' , '` notice the space before and after the comma

this is how you should do it: `$string = explode(',', $string);`

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: Yup, I check. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you have a string and use explode each element is still a string.
Means it's "1". And is_int("1") is false.
You'd need is_numeric()